# Android application not displaying in market

Tags: android, google-play

I have publish an application on market but is unable to see it on the market website. I hear that is may be due to the /lib in the folder. I got the /lib and have got the admob library in it. I need it. If i delete it, there would be an error. And changing from my current `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>` to `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />` doesn't help either. adding the extra targetSdkVersion just creates an error. Tried a direct url link also didn't work. Any solution for it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="calc.calc"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".Calculator"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"
/>
```

Comment: when you upload your application in android market?

Comment: added it about a day ago. till now still not visible. :( I put all content settings to everyone and all devices too. still not visible as of now.

Comment: @Hend I see your app on my phone running Android 2.1. Though I published an app this morning and don't see it after 7+ hours now. This is pretty frustrating when everyone else says their app shows up in under an hour.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Thien for your affirmation. I am able to search it now with other search words. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a green checkmark and can see a label with the text saying "Published" in the top right corner of your app description in the Android Market Console (like [here](http://www.kreci.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/market.jpg)) then you may just have to wait some time.

In my case, app upgrades are not visible to all of the users instantly.

Comment: Mine has no errors displaying. :( It shows a green text published

Comment: "SG Part Time Salary Calc" - is this your application's name? If yes, then it's visible on the website and I have just downloaded it on my phone.

Comment: yes it is. How are you able to be able to see it when im unable to view from market?

Comment: @Hend - hmm... maybe it's a network or country issue? Are you sure that your app is available in all countries? You can set allowed ones in the Market Console. You can also try using some proxy service and with "clear" browser (in private mode) navigate to the Market Website and search for your app (using package name) - to check if it's visible to the others.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution. I am able to see the published app now while using other search keywords. Thanks. :)